# How to create a free items server in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I mean like those servers that have chests full of items that never become empty.

I am not a game programmer but I think it shouldn't be that hard and I can try it myself.

I think they use the TShock server but I don't know any of the rest.

I googled but found nothing about it.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was answered [here](https://forum.dark-gaming.com/t/how-to-create-a-free-items-server-in-terraria/27873/2?u=miloo):

---

Directions:

1. Download the latest version of TShock from [Releases](https://%20https://github.com/Pryaxis/TShock/releases).
2. Create a shortcut of “TShock.Server” by right clicking on it and selecting “Create shortcut”. You will use this shortcut whenever launching the server in the future.
3. Right click on the shortcut you created, and select “Properties”.
4. Go to the end of the target line and add a space and `-ignoreversions`.
5. Go to the [tShock5 Plugins page](https://github.com/RenderBr/tShock-v5-plugins), and scroll down until you find “InfiniteChestsV3.dll”. Click on it and download it.
6. Locate the .dll file in your files, copy it, and paste it in the “serverplugins” folder of TShock.
7. Run the “TShock.Server” shortcut you created. That will open a console.

   If you’ve followed the steps correctly thus far, you will see under the yellow text that the plugin “InfiniteChestsV3” has been successfully initiated.
8. Create a new world or load an already existing one. To create a new one, type “n” and follow the prompts. To select a pre-existing world, type the number located on the same line as the world name. If you create a new world, you will need to wait until it is finished generating and select it the same way you would an already existing world.

   Take note of the `/setup <numbers>`. Upon joining the server, you will need to type /setup  in the in-game chat in order to set your account up.
9. Open Terraria, go to multiplayer, and select Host & Play. Once you reach your worlds, select the same one you selected in the console. Otherwise, it will not find the server. Tweak settings as liked. When you reach the select/enter a password screen, click “Accept”. No password has been set yet.
10. Set up your account using the setup command & numbers mentioned. Follow the chat prompt given after entering the setup command & numbers to create and login to your account:

    `/user add <username> <password> owner`

    `/login <username> <password>`

    Upon logging into your account, type `/group addperm owner *`. This will give you access to all permissions/commands.
11. Place/find the desired chest you wish to auto-refill. Then, you will type /chest refill 0 into the chat and open said chest. This will make this chest auto-refill its contents upon closing and re-opening it. Keep in mind that this will NOT create stacks of 999; You will have to add quantities manually via the /i command

---

- I also added for the sake of completeness that we need to add the items we want in the chest before issuing the “/chest refill 0” command, and any items we put in the chest afterwards will be gone.
- Also we can disable the chest auto refill with “/chest refill -1”